# AS3 Calling method in another swf file using workers threads

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, worker

I currently have a worker thread loading a external swf file successfully. But how do I call a function in the loaded swf file ?

This is the class located in the external swf file.

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class BackgroundProcesses extends Sprite {
        public function BackgroundProcesses()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function EncryptTheImage(_imageToEncrypte:Bitmap):ByteArray
        {
            // Encrypted the image here
            var _imageInEncryptedBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            return _imageInEncryptedBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Flex Mobile mxml file:

```
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

protected function LoadWorkerSwfFile(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var workerLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    workerLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    workerLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
    workerLoader.load(new URLRequest("BackgroundProcesses.swf"));
}

private function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var workerBytes:ByteArray = event.target.data as ByteArray;
    var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(workerBytes);
    bgWorker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, WorkerIsRunning);


    bgWorker.start();
}

private function WorkerIsRunning(event:flash.events.Event):void
{
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else can correct me, but I don't think you can access another worker's properties and methods directly, nor do I think you are suppose to be able to by design. Instead, you're supposed to pass messages and data back and forth between them to communicate and send/get work results.

This may help: [Communicating between workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2f73111e7a180bd0-5856a8af1390d64d08c-7ffe.html)